# Why doesn't this simple RewriteRule work anymore and why does google keep seeing it?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Some time ago (I think a couple of years) this simple RewriteRule in my htaccess stopped working.

```
RewriteRule tags/ tags.php [L]
```

It worked for years, then a day after a server change or a server upgrade or switch to php-fpm (I don't remember) it stopped working.

I solved it by deleting it, and sending all my links directly to the tags.php file.

This rule is part of a small CMS that I use for many of my sites. The sites work and everything works correctly.

But punctually when I create a new site, after a few days google sends me a warning telling me that the url mysite.com/tags/ creates an error 404.

And this is strange, because the url mysite.com/tags/ no longer exists for years now in my sites, nor in my sitemaps, I am sure because it is used only once in the main menu of my sites, and has been replaced with mysite.com/tags.php.
Above all it cannot exist in new sites. At first I didn't pay much attention to it on old sites. Probably google may have seen it in the old sites, and haven't forgotten it yet, but surely can't have seen it in the new sites.

So, I have a couple of unanswered questions.

The first and perhaps most important to understand: How does google see the url mysite.com/tags/? Is it possible that google reads my htaccess to understand what kind of url I'm going to create?

Second: how can I solve the problem permanently?

--------------------------update---------------------

Sorry for the delay with which I reply (summer vacation).

Regarding anubhava's answer, I have a doubt, but it's my fault, maybe I omitted part of the code.

The next rule says:

```
RewriteRule ^tags-([^/]+)\/$ tags.php?letter=$1 [L]
```

and makes work some urls like:
mysite.com/tags-k/

and these urls work, but if I put a 301 redirect on tags.php, will they still work?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, Google (or any other) search bot cannot read your .htaccess
2. It is difficult to figure out how search bot found `/tags` URI but it is definitely hidden somewhere in your web pages.

Now to tell search bots that `/tags` doesn't exist is to use a redirect rule with `R=301`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^tags(/.*)?$ /tags.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

With this `301` rule search bot will eventually let go old `/tags/` result and will remember `/tags.php` only.